# Plotting data onto highchart chart when series data uses named objects

Tags: highcharts

I have a working, simple highchart chart which plots 'score' against 'time'.  There's a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/akfwsq1e/.

The series data is in the form `[time, score]`:

```
"data": [
    [1540398983, 3], 
    [1540398983, 2], 
    [1540398983, 3], 
    [1540398983, 2], 
    [1540398983, 4], 
    [1540485383, 3]
]
```

However, I need to append more meta-data as I'd like to extend the chart with filters etc in future.  This means that the data from the API is returning named objects:

```
"data": [
    { 'dateCompleted': 1540398983, 'score': 3, 'category': 'A' },
    { 'dateCompleted': 1540398983, 'score': 2, 'category': 'C' },
    { 'dateCompleted': 1540398983, 'score': 3, 'category': 'A' },
    { 'dateCompleted': 1540398983, 'score': 2, 'category': 'B' },
    { 'dateCompleted': 1540398983, 'score': 4, 'category': 'A' },
    { 'dateCompleted': 1540485383, 'score': 3, 'category': 'C' }
]
```

For now I'm not too concerned with the filtering, I just need to get the chart to plot the same as it does when using simple object values.  When I use named values though the chart silently fails to plot anything.

I can't seem to figure out from the documentation how Highcharts 'knows' which values from a named-object to plot.

Can anyone suggest how to get this working?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you won't change the structure of object recieved from server, you could implement your own data parse function, which takes the data with specific structure, and returns the data specially prepared for Highcharts.

Actually it's a bit piece of cake, so I wrote that function:

```
  function mapData(data) {
    let arr;
    arr = data.map(point => {
      return {
        x: point.dateCompleted,
        y: point.score,
        category: point.category
      }
    })
    return arr
  }
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/1jp8v6ns/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to call the values to plot 'x' and 'y' (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data). So this works:

```
"data": [
    { 'x': 1540398983, 'y': 3, 'category': 'A' },
    { 'x': 1540398983, 'y': 2, 'category': 'C' },
    { 'x': 1540398983, 'y': 3, 'category': 'A' },
    { 'x': 1540398983, 'y': 2, 'category': 'B' },
    { 'x': 1540398983, 'y': 4, 'category': 'A' },
    { 'x': 1540485383, 'y': 3, 'category': 'C' }
]
```